# Ionic: Floating Menu

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to implement a floating menu like it is shown here: [CSS Floating Menu](http://www.quackit.com/css/codes/css_floating_menu.cfm)
But when i implement it like in the following [Ionic Playground](http://play.ionic.io/app/51d08363858a) It does not work. When i scroll the view the floating menu does not stay fixed at the position i defined. It scrolls up.

So how can i implement a floating menu in ionic?

Comment: Can you create a demo of your code please?

Comment: It does work from here.

Comment: Menu is fixed in all the demo links.

Comment: I editet my post and added ionic playground to show that the floating menu is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the floating content outside the ion-content worked. And edited style to avoid overlapping of floating content above the header....

```
    <ion-pane>
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>

          <div class="floating-menu">
              <h3>Floating Menu</h3>
              <a href="http://www.quackit.com/css/">CSS</a>
              <a href="http://www.quackit.com/html/">HTML</a>
              <a href="http://www.quackit.com/javascript/">JavaScript</a>
              <a href="http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/">ColdFusion</a>
              <a href="http://www.quackit.com/database/">Database</a>
          </div>

          <ion-content>
          ...
          </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
```

CSS

```
div.floating-menu {position:fixed;background:#fff4c8;border:1px solid #ffcc00;width:150px;z-index:100;top:44px;}
```